# Development To Staging to Production

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssis, ssas

Tools that I have: SQL Server Database/SSIS/SSAS/SSRS
Different servers for Dev/Stage/Prod
Different DB for Dev/Stage/Prod (SSMS/SSAS)

Goal: Create something in dev environment. Pass it to Staging. After verification, pass it to production.

Question: How do I do that?

once I make some tables, packages, cubes, packages in dev, how do i push it to staging server and finally production server?

Comment: John, welcome to SO. While your question is a good one, it's not one that's really suitable for StackOverflow. StackOverflow is designed, at least in theory, for specific technical questions that have definitive, objective answers. In addition, questions should be specific enough that [you can't imagine an entire book being written on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Given that your question deals primarily with databases, it likely belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com), so I've voted to migrate it over there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the version you're using, so I'll just assume something other than 2012. The information below applies to versions 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2.

For SSIS - see this:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966389.aspx. Short story- there is a package deployment utility that you use in BIDS that can use to put together a manifest that allows an admin to push all your packages to a target location, either on the file system or in MSDB.

For SSRS - see this: http://rsbuild.codeplex.com/ for a tool that you can use to deploy reports. You can also write an RSS script to give to an admin with your RDL files to deploy. You can learn more about this and other options at : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/2967/

For SSAS - there is a deployment wizard you open from the Analysis Services folder in the Microsoft SQL Server 20xx program group (from the Start menu). You point it to an ASDATABASE file and step through the wizard to configure any settings you want (like changed connection strings) and produce an XMLA script file that you can hand off to an admin for execution on the target server. Learn more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174817.aspx

Answer (score 1):

on SSIS you can generate your deployment manifest and send it to DBAs to do the deployment

on SSAS there are several deployment ways like BIDS and Synchronize Database Wizard but eh best option is the Deployment Wizardo that enables you to generate an incremental deployment script that updates the cube and dimension structures. Can also customize how roles and partitions are handled. I usually use it with the /a mode that runs the wizard but doesnt actually deploy the cube, only creates the script then you send the script to the DBAs to do the actuall deployment

on SSRS send the report file to the DBAs and give them structions about the folder to upload it into. Also ask for any datasources requiered to be created

Answer (score 0):

Not to shill for a private company, but my organization uses http://www.sqldelta.com/, a fairly easy to use tool. Allows piece by piece comparisons of database objects and optionally database table data.